# Compute efficiently Max and Min on data stream

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, optimization

I'm working in C with a stream of data. Basically I receive a column array of 6 elements every n milliseconds. I would like to compute the max value for each row of data.

To make this clear this is how my data looks like (this is a toy example, actually I'll have thousand of columns acquired):

```
[6] [-10] [5]
[1] [5]   [3]
[5] [30]  [10]
[2] [-10] [0]
[-2][5]   [10]
[-5][0]   [1]
```

So basically (as I said) I receive a column of data every n milliseconds, and I want to compute the max and min value row-wise. So in my previous example my result would be:

```
max_values=[6,5,30,2,10,1]
min_values=[-10,1,5,-10,-2,-5]
```

I want to point out that I have no access to the full matrix, I can only work over single columns of 6 elements that I receive every n milliseconds.

This is my simple code algorithm so far (I'm omitting the whole code since it's part of a bigger project):

```
 for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(input[i]>temp_max[i]){
            temp_max[i]=input[i];
        }
        if(input[i]<temp_min[i]){
            temp_min[i]=input[i];
        }

    }
```

Where `input`, `temp_max` and `temp_min` are all float arrays of dimension 6.
Basically my code executes this piece of code everytime a new input array is available and updates the maximum and minimum accordingly.

Since I'm interested in performance (this is going to run on an embedded system), is there any way to improve this part of the code? Calling a comparison for each single element of the 2 arrays doesn't seem the most smart idea.

Comment: What kind of hardware architecture do you use? Is it ARM-based? Regarding the target architecture, the current code could be quite slow.

Comment: @JérômeRichard My final architecture is a Avnet Ultra96-V2. Any suggestions are appreciated! Right now I'm developing the code using standard C (just to make it work from the algorithmic point of view) then I'll import it into Vivado HLS and optimize it accordingly

Comment: (Note that there are tags ~embedded with [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded), [**SIGNAL**PROCESSING](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-systems) and [**ELECTRICAL** *ENGINEERING*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded).) *one sextuple of float values every n **milli**seconds*&*I'll have thousand of [sextuples] acquired* Do you need *extrema every time "thousand" have been amassed*, or *running min&max sextuples*? If the latter, does it ***need*** to include every value of the latest sextuple?

Comment: (I would exchange the designations *row* and *column*, but why do you use them in the first place?)

Comment: (For *iterables*, there is `minmax_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)`  in [C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). If you can't use it, know what a *forward iterator* is but not `minmax_element()`, have a look at the specification just the same.)

Comment: The code design (six-tuple + row/columns) is forced by other costraints of my project (hardware, previous developments by other people ecc...).
I'm using arrays of 6 elements since my hardware sensors outputs an array of 6 elements every n milliseconds.
With "thousand of elements" I mean that I don't know a priori how many elements I'll get in input, so basically I have to compute the min and max over an undefinite amount of time, then the sensor (using an interrupt) will arbitrarly decide when to stop acquiring data and my system will start computing other things

Comment: So basically I can't store anything locally (due to costraint + I don't know how many samples I'll get in input) and I need to compute my min-max values over an indefinite number of samples. So basically I'll store the new min or max value temporarely and update them if I receive new min-max values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Branching is slow**, especially on embedded systems. **Scalar computation too**.
Hopefully, your targeted processor seems to be an ARM-based processor supporting the NEON **SIMD instruction set** (apparently one based on a 64-bits ARM-V8 A53 architecture). NEON can compute 4 32-bits floating-point operations in a row. This should be much faster than the current code (which compilers apparently fail to vectorize).

Here is an example code (untested):

```c
void minmax_optim(float temp_min[6], float temp_max[6], float input[6]) {
    /* Compute the first 4 floats */

    float32x4_t vInput = vld1q_f32(input);
    float32x4_t vMin = vld1q_f32(temp_min);
    float32x4_t vMax = vld1q_f32(temp_max);

    vMin = vminq_f32(vInput, vMin);
    vMax = vmaxq_f32(vInput, vMax);
    vst1q_f32(temp_min, vMin);
    vst1q_f32(temp_max, vMax);

    /* Remainder 2 floats */

    float32x2_t vLastInput = vld1_f32(input+4);
    float32x2_t vLastMin = vld1_f32(temp_min+4);
    float32x2_t vLastMax = vld1_f32(temp_max+4);

    vLastMin = vmin_f32(vLastInput, vLastMin);
    vLastMax = vmax_f32(vLastInput, vLastMax);
    vst1_f32(temp_min+4, vLastMin);
    vst1_f32(temp_max+4, vLastMax);
}
```

The resulting code should be much faster. One can see on [goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oGcjcG) that the number of instructions of this vectorized implementation is drastically smaller than the reference implementation without any conditional jump instructions.

Answer (score 3):

With random input data (i.e. unordered data), it'll be pretty hard (aka impossible) to find min/max without a comparison per element.

You may get some minor improvement from something like:

```
temp_max[0]=input[0];
temp_min[0]=input[0];
for(int i=1;i<6;i++){             // Only 1..6
    if(input[i]>temp_max[i]){
        temp_max[i]=input[i];
    }
    else  // If current element was larger than max, you don't need to check min
    {
        if(input[i]<temp_min[i]){
            temp_min[i]=input[i];
        }
    }
}
```

but I doubt this will be a significant improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You nailed it -- you have to keep a temporary max and min arrays. Unfortunately, if we're talking strictly C, it seems to be the single possible and thus most performant algorithm possible.

Since you've mentioned it's going to run on embedded system (but omitted which), please make sure you have hardware floating point support. If there isn't, that's going to be high performance penality. If you have high-end hardware, you can look for availability of vector instructions, but then that's platform-specific, possibly by use of assembly.

Answer (score 1):

To my impression the approach as such cannot be substantially improved, as the input is not available as a whole. That being said, the inner comparisons can be compacted. The assignemnts

```
if(input[i]>temp_max[i]){
    temp_max[i]=input[i];
}
if(input[i]<temp_min[i]){
    temp_min[i]=input[i];
}
```

can be improved to

```
if(input[i]>temp_max[i]){
    temp_max[i]=input[i];
}
else if(input[i]<temp_min[i]){
    temp_min[i]=input[i];
}
```

because if the current value replaces the temporary maximum, it cannot also replace the temporary minimum (assuming some sensible initialization).

Comment: @P__J__ are you talking about `temp_min[i]==temp_max[i]` (Why wouldn't it work?) or about aliasing `temp_min==temp_max` (Why should it work?)?

Answer (score 0):

Only for max but it is easy to expand

```
#define MAX(a,b,c) (a) > (b) ? ((b) > (c) ? (b) : (a) > (c) ? (a) : (c) ) : (b) > (c) ? (b) : (c) 


void rowmax(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *result, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        result[index] = MAX(a[index], b[index], c[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit your solution?